# How are you supposed to use upscaling technologies such as DLSS when programming at a low level with Vulkan or DirectX?

Tags: graphics, directx, vulkan

I don't understand what upscaling technologies such as NVidia's DLSS and AMD's Contrast Adaptive Sharpening (CAS) are very well, but I was wondering how they work from the Vulkan and Direct API point of view when you as a programmer build the rendering part of the engine in your code. The idea is to render to a lower resolution framebuffer, and then the above technology I mentioned is supposed to upscale it, I think using AI neural networks on the GPU device. What sorts of things do you need to do? What API calls do you need to make to use this in the Vulkan or DirectX code?

Comment: In the CAS case you can use in shader code (HLSL for DirectX, etc) https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/FidelityFX-SDK/blob/main/docs/samples/contrast-adaptive-sharpening.md

Comment: I think DLSS is something you "plug" on top of the graphics API. I've never used it (and I am thus posting a comment rather than an answer), but that's what they seem do state on their "[`Getting started`](https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/dlss/get-started)" and that _looks_ coherent with the [Vulkan header](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DLSS/blob/main/include/nvsdk_ngx_vk.h).

Again, I may be completely wrong, I never used DLSS.